# Load video file to html5 player with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

I have little problem with video. I just created service where user is going to see on every page, just one help video for our application.

**SITUATION**

When he click on video icon, pop-up is going to be open - this action:

```
 var getVideoModal = function (video) {
  var path = '/application/files/help/tutorial_videos/'+video;
  $('div#modal-video').modal('show');
  $("#modal-video").draggable({
    handle: ".modal-header"
  });
  $('h3#modal-header-video').html(video);
  console.log(path);
  $("#video-help").find("#videoPath").attr("src", path);
  centerModal();
}
```

When pop-up is opened, there (in popup body) is `<video>` html5 element

```
  <video id="video-help" width="530" controls>
    <source id="videoPath" src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Pop-up si working, but video not.

**PROBLEM:**

I have problem because i have video stored in "*/application/help/videos*". This path is forbidden and you can't call this URL in browser. How can i load videos from this restricted area with PHP (which have access, through file system) to my video player

I need something like:

```
  <video id="video-help" width="530" controls>
        <source id="videoPath" src="whatever.php?video=loaded.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Your path is `/application/files/help/tutorial_videos/` or `application/help/videos` ?

Comment: It doesn't matter - is restricted and it is important.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/174708/apache2-how-do-i-restrict-access-to-a-directory-but-allow-access-to-one-file-w) is what you want ? And then modify accordingly to grant access to other videos...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay guys, i found soloution (PHP).

Here is great PHP Class for video streaming in PHP:

http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

It is all what i need to have.

**Note:** You need to have video in supported format for HTML5  - I am using OGG -> *sample.ogv*

Answer (score 5):

You can effectively go with PHP to send video data from a restricted folder access. Open, read the file and send data.

You can also make it working if the user move the player timeline by sending data by range. The code below do that :

```
    $my_video_basename = //filter to have a trust filename

    $file = "/application/help/videos" . $my_video_basename;

    if(!file_exists($file)) return; 

    $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');      
    $size   = filesize($file); // File size 
    $length = $size;           // Content length
    $start  = 0;               // Start byte
    $end    = $size - 1;       // End byte  
    header('Content-type: video/mp4');
    header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
        $c_start = $start;              
        $c_end   = $end;                
        list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
        if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;      
        }              
        if ($range == '-') {            
            $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
        }else{         
            $range  = explode('-', $range); 
            $c_start = $range[0];           
            $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
        }
        $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
        if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) { 
            header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
            header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
            exit;      
        }
        $start  = $c_start;             
        $end    = $c_end;               
        $length = $end - $start + 1;    
        fseek($fp, $start);             
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    }                  
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    $buffer = 1024 * 8;
    while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) { 
        if ($p + $buffer > $end) {      
            $buffer = $end - $p + 1;        
        }              
        set_time_limit(0);              
        echo fread($fp, $buffer);       
        ob_flush();    
    }
    fclose($fp);       
    exit();
```

Comment: Is this method working with HTML5 player (video tag)?

Comment: This works quite good for me when dealing with large files (for files > 2GB you must run a x64 system, otherwise the fopen + f*** functions fail). The `set_time_limit()` should be put outside the loop ;)

Comment: spend tow days looking for this , works fantastic

Answer (score 1):

**Backend Controller Dashboard to Play/Stop video for FrontEnd Users**

```
 <?php 
include 'conf.php';


    $sql="SELECT * FROM videos";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $file=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);



    $sqlnew="SELECT * FROM videos where Vid_is_active='Yes'";
    $resultnew=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlnew);
    $filenew=mysqli_fetch_all($resultnew,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>  
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>



<script type="application/javascript">

var existData = '<?php echo @$filenew[0]['Vid_is_active']; ?>'; 
var existId = '<?php echo @$filenew[0]['Vid_id']; ?>';
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $(document).on('click', ".table .btn", function (e) {       
        $('#bsModal2').modal('show');
        e.preventDefault();
        id = $(this).attr('id')
        valu = $(this).val()

        if(valu==='Yes'){
        $(".stp_" + id).show();
        $(".btn-str").hide();
        }
        if(valu==='No'){
        $(".btn-str").show();
        $(".stp_" + id).hide();
        window.location.reload();
        //return false;
        }

    //return false; 
    if(existData==valu){
        $('#bsModal').modal('show');
        return false;

    }else{
        $.ajax({  
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/Ashish/VD/update.php',  
                type: 'POST',  
                dataType: 'json',  
                data: {"id": id,"value":valu},
                success: function (resultData) {  
                    console.log(resultData);
                    //update duration   
                    //window.location.reload();
                    if(valu=='Yes') {               
                     duartionupdat(id,valu);
                    }
                     //window.location.reload();

                }, 
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                    console.log('Error in Operation');  
                }  
            }); 
    }

    });


    function duartionupdat(id,valu){
        //alert(valu);
        var counter = 0;
            setInterval(function(){     
        counter++;          
                $.ajax({  
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/Ashish/VD/updateduration.php',  
                type: 'POST',  
                dataType: 'json',  
                data: {"id": id,"value":counter},
                success: function (resultData) {  
                }, 
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                    console.log('Error in Operation');  
                }  
            });     
        }, 1000);
    }

});

</script>   
                <div class="example" style="width: 221px;  background-color: #2faede;    margin: 2px 1202px 0;">
                <h3 class="txt" style="margin: 3px 65px -34px; color: white;">Shuffle</h3>
                <input id="toggle-event" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
                <!--<div id="console-event"></div>-->
                <script>
                    $(function() {
                        $('#toggle-event').change(function() {
                        var t =$(this).prop('checked');
                        alert(t);
                        if(t==true){    
                        $(".example").css('background-color','green')
                        $(".txt").css('color','white')
                        }else{
                            $(".example").css('background-color','red')
                            $(".txt").css('color','white')
                        }


                            //$('#console-event').html('Toggle: ' + $(this).prop('checked'))
                        })
                    })
                </script>
            </div>          



 <div class="modal fade" id="bsModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: #e0fde0;">
            <div class="modal-header" style="margin: 10px 10px 11px;">
                <button type="button"  style="margin: -47px -43px 0px;"  class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4  style="margin: 0px 24px 15px;" class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Video Started!! Do not Refresh the page after play video!</h4>
            </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Sr.No.</th>
      <th scope="col">Video</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <!--<th scope="col">Path</th>-->
      <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
  $i=1;
  foreach($file as $files){  
  $video = $files['Vid_path']. $files['Vid_name'];

  ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $i;  ?></th>
      <td><video style="background-color: #2faede;" id="myVideo" width='100' height='50'  ><source id="source_video" src="<?php echo $video  ?>" type="video/mp4"></video>

      </td>
      <td><?php echo $files['Vid_name'];  ?></td>
      <!--<td><?php echo $files['Vid_path'];  ?></td>-->
      <td>
        <button type="button" value="Yes" id="<?php echo $files['Vid_id'];  ?>"
          class="btn btn-str btn-success str_<?php echo $files['Vid_id']; ?>">Start</button>


        <button value="No" style="display:none;" id="<?php echo $files['Vid_id'];  ?>" type="button"
          class="btn btn-stp btn-danger stp_<?php echo $files['Vid_id']; ?>">Stop</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
$i++;
} 

 ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Fornt-end VideoPlayer**

```
<?php 
    include 'conf.php';

    $sql="SELECT * FROM videos where  Vid_is_active='Yes'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $file=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $filename= @$file[0]['Vid_name'];

?>  

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {    
        setInterval(function(){ 
                $.ajax({  
                    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Ashish/VD/api.php',  
                    type: 'POST',  
                    dataType: 'json',  
                    data: 'Yes',  
                    success: function (resultData) {  
                        console.log(resultData); 
                        var path  =resultData[0]['Path'];
                        var vName = resultData[0]['videoName'];
                        var duration  =resultData[0]['duration'];
                        console.log(resultData);
                        if(resultData[0]['Status']==false){
                            //alert('Stoped');
                            window.location.reload();
                        }else{
                        $("#myVideo").html('<source id="source_video" src="'+path+vName+'" type="video/mp4">');

                        document.getElementById("myVideo").currentTime = duration;
                        //window.location.reload();

                        }

                    }, 
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                        console.log('Error in Operation');  
                    }  
                });  

            }, 2000);

    }  
    </script>

                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='column'>
                                <div class='card'>                          
                                    <video id="myVideo" width='1410' height='710'  autoplay ></video>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**API.php**

```
    include 'conf.php';
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 


        $query='Select * from videos  where Vid_is_active="Yes"';
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $file=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $result=array();

        if(!empty($file)){
        //echo $sql;die;
        $result[] = array('duration'=>$file[0]["duration"],'id'=>$file[0]["Vid_id"],'Status'=>$file[0]["Vid_status"],'Path'=>$file[0]["Vid_path"],'videoName'=>$file[0]["Vid_name"] ,'message' => 'Video List');
        }else{

        $result[]=array('Status'=>false, 'message'=>'No vidoes are Active');    
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
```

**Update.php**

```
    include 'conf.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 





    $sql="SELECT * FROM videos where Vid_is_active='Yes'";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $file=mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    if($_POST['value']=='Yes'){


           $query='UPDATE videos SET Vid_status = "Started" , Vid_is_active="'.$_POST["value"].'" WHERE Vid_id ='.$_POST["id"].''; 
        }else{
         $query='UPDATE videos SET Vid_status = "Stop" , duration=0, Vid_is_active="'.$_POST["value"].'" WHERE Vid_id ='.$_POST["id"].'';
        }
        //echo $query;die;

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $results=array();
        $results[] = array('id'=>$_POST["id"],'Message'=>'Updated');

        echo json_encode($results);
```

**Updateduration.php**

```
    include 'conf.php';
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'); 

    $query='UPDATE videos SET duration ='.$_POST["value"].'  WHERE Vid_id ='.$_POST["id"].'';
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $results=array();
    $results[] = array('id'=>$_POST["id"],'Message'=>'Duration Updated');
    echo json_encode($results);
```